# How to make zip file to the 'sublime-package' file?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Now, I am using sublime, I install a theme named Material Theme. I don't like some color for the code highlight, so I want to change it.

```
/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
```

In this path, I finde the theme file.

```
Material Theme.sublime-package
```

But it can't be open. So I change the extension to zip, then I can uncompress it. Then I find this thems's config file, I change the color for this theme.

Now, I find a problem, I can't let the uncompress file back the the extension 'sublime-package'. If I can't turn it back, this change for color will not work.

So, I want to know how to change the file back?

Comment: This depends on your operating system. Also, this may be better off asked on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: You can create a new file in you user folder for the overrided vales without modifying the original one inside the zip. What file do you want to change?

Comment: In addition, in windows you can open winrar, then browse the file and edit the files inside, and finally save it and say yes when winrar tells you to overwrite changes to compressed file. In Linux Mint (and maybe others) you can do the same opening the file directly with the default compressed files program.